# How to group list items into tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of numbers, how can I group every `n` numbers into a tuple?

For example, if I have a list `a = range(10)` and I want to group every 5 items into a tuple, so:

```
b = [(0,1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8,9)]
```

How can I do this? I also want to raise an error if `len(a)` is not an integer multiple of `n`.

Comment: Have a look at the itertools.grouper recipe...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/1217270

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [tuple(a[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(a), 5)]
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [18]: def f(lst,n):    
    ...:     if len(lst)%n != 0:
    ...:         raise ValueError("{} is not a multiple of {}".format(len(lst),n))
    ...:     return zip(*[iter(lst)]*n)

In [19]: lst = range(10)

In [20]: f(lst,5)
Out[20]: [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]

In [21]: f(range(9),5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-814a68e0035f> in <module>()
----> 1 f(range(9),5)

<ipython-input-18-3ca911a04fd3> in f(lst, n)
      1 def f(lst,n):
      2     if len(lst)%n != 0:
----> 3         raise ValueError("{} is not a multiple of {}".format(len(lst),n))
      4     return zip(*[iter(lst)]*n)

ValueError: 9 is not a multiple of 5
```

Comment: This looks great! Thanks! Although I'm not sure how did `zip(*[iter(lst)]*n)` work...

Comment: @LWZ -- if you read through the questions, linked in the comments, you will find different implementations of the actual splitting with corresponding discussion...

Answer (score 1):

determine that N is your group length

```
if (len(your_list)%n==0):
    wish_list = [ tuple(your_list[i:i+N]) for i in range(0, len(your_list), N) ]
else:
    raise Exception("not divisible by N")
```