# in Python, How to join a list of tuples into one list?

Tags: python, tuples

Following on my previous question [How to group list items into tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266593/how-to-group-list-items-into-tuple)

If I have a list of tuples, for example

```
a = [(1,3),(5,4)]
```

How can I unpack the tuples and reformat it into one single list

```
b = [1,3,5,4]
```

I think this also has to do with the `iter` function, but I really don't know how to do this. Please enlighten me.

Comment: pretty much exact duplicate ...

Comment: I had hoped that there was a "splat" operator I could use for this, but unfortunately it isn't permitted specifically for comprehensions :( https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#id10

Comment: Use sum as in this very [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/13168369)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
b = [i for sub in a for i in sub]
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: oh yeah, that was easy, what was I thinking...

Comment: Nice one. I had to think about it for a second - _"where did sub come from at the end?"_

Comment: Why/how does this work?

Comment: Please explain how that works, I am also confused by the double loop

Comment: @ruief @Asara the double loop works exactly as if you wrote it out as a nested for-loop: `for sub in a` picks out each sublist (or in this case, each tuple) of `a`, and then `for i in sub` picks out each element in each sublist, which is put together to form the resultant list. Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Didn't know you could double loop in a list comp, nice. Answer works and is concise so have upvoted... but damn that syntax is hard to read.

Answer (score 15):

```
In [11]: list(itertools.chain(*a))
Out[11]: [1, 3, 5, 4]
```

If you just need to iterate over `1, 3, 5, 4`, you can get rid of the `list()` call.

Comment: What's the point of `itertools.chain.from_iterable` then if you can just do that?

Comment: @Volatility: Lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over the list a and unpack the tuples:

```
l = []
for x,y in a:
   l.append(x)
   l.append(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
a = [(1,3),(5,4)]
b = []

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        b.append(j)

print b
```

This will only handle the tuples inside the list (a) tho. You need to add if-else statements if you want to parse in loose variables too, like;

```
a = [(1,3),(5,4), 23, [21, 22], {'somevalue'}]
b = []

for i in a:
    if type(i) == (tuple) or type(i) == (list) or type(i) == (set):
        for j in i:
            b.append(j)
    else:
        b.append(i)

print b
```

Comment: Use `isinstance(i, collections.Iterable)` instead of the type checking (assuming `collections` has already been imported)

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
b = [i for i in itertools.chain(*[(1,3),(5,4)])]
```