# Python 2.7: Convert list of multiple tuples to a single list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following list of multiple tuples:

```
[('1', 'Mak'), ('2', 'Sam'), ('3', 'John')]
```

Type: `<type 'list'>`

Convert to:

```
['1,Mak\n', '2,Sam\n', '3,John\n']
```

Comment: Does something like `[",".join(t) + "\n" for t in lst]` not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269161/in-python-how-to-join-a-list-of-tuples-into-one-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`string.format`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter) with a list comprehension for Python 2.6+

```
['{}\n'.format(','.join(i)) for i in arr]

# ['1,Mak\n', '2,Sam\n', '3,John\n']
```

Or with Python 3.6+ using [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

```
[f"{','.join(i)}\n" for i in arr]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
l = [('1', 'Mak'), ('2', 'Sam'), ('3', 'John')]
l = [x + ',' + y + '\n' for x, y in l]
```

so, now `l` becomes:
`['1,Mak\n', '2,Sam\n', '3,John\n']`

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension.

```
l = [('1', 'Mak'), ('2', 'Sam'), ('3', 'John')]
print [",".join(i)+ "\n" for i in l]
```

*or*

Using a `map` with `lambda`.

**Ex:**

```
l = [('1', 'Mak'), ('2', 'Sam'), ('3', 'John')]
print map(lambda x: "{0}\n".format(",".join(x)), l)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this -

```
>>> l = [('1', 'Mak'), ('2', 'Sam'), ('3', 'John')]
>>> new_list = []
>>>
>>> for x in l:
...     new_list.append('%s%s' % (','.join(x), '\n'))
...
>>> new_list
['1,Mak\n', '2,Sam\n', '3,John\n']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  map and lambda to solve this problem .

```
#input
your_list = [('1', 'Mak'), ('2', 'Sam'), ('3', 'John')]
#result
result_list = list(map(lambda x:x[0]+x[1]+"\n",your_list))
```