# Converting list of tuples to just a list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have:

```
my_column = [('Me ',), ('If ',), ('Will ',), ('If ',)]
```

I want to turn this into a simple list of strings:

```
['Me','If','Will','If']
```

Comment: What have you tried for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Python, How to join a list of tuples into one list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269161/in-python-how-to-join-a-list-of-tuples-into-one-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to convert a list of tuples into a list.

```python
pairs = [('Me ',), ('If ',), ('Will ',), ('If ',)]
# using list comprehension
out = [item for t in pairs for item in t]
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
['Me ', 'If ', 'Will ', 'If ']
```

If want to remove duplicates then replace [] notation with {} to create a set.

```
out = {item for t in a for item in t}
```

**Output:**

```
{'Me ', 'If ', 'Will '}
```

Comment: has there got a way to remove the space at the end of each of the word in the output list?

Comment: If want to strip whitespace from words use `out = [item.strip() for t in a for item in t]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.chain`.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*my_column))
['Me ', 'If ', 'Will ', 'If ']
```

or

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(my_column))
['Me ', 'If ', 'Will ', 'If ']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_column = [('Me ',), ('If ',), ('Will ',), ('If ',)]
list=list()
for i in my_column:
    for j in i:
        list.append(j)
print(list)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.